# after converting my tkinter py file to exe i get an error

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

My Program works perfectly as long as i run it as a .py file but after converting to exe i get this error

```
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:\Users\MYNAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI107362\tkfilebrowser\images\file.png": no such file or directory
```

Why is Trying to open that file here is my code

```
 name = askopenfilename( parent=root, initialdir='/', initialfile='tmp', \
 filetypes=[("JPG", "*.jpg"), ("MP3", "*.mp3"), ("TXT", "*.txt")])
```

I used pyinstaller for converting

Comment: I am not sure the error is related to the line your pointed out. Is it possible that file.png is an image you use for your GUI ?

Comment: No I don't have I don't even have a file that's called that and the path showing in the error is not the real path of my machine

Comment: I have three other functions that do the same thing and they all work as a script but not in the exe

Comment: _MEI107362 is the temporary file where pyinstaller bootloader is unpacking all the stuff packed in the exe file. Your error tells me that probably a piece of code is trying to access file.png using a relative path built using `__file__` to determine the current path. This in MHO is not linked to askopenfilename. As usual, creating a Minimal Reproductible Exemple would help a lot.

Comment: from tkinter import * 

    from tkfilebrowser import askopenfilename

    root = Tk()

    def tri():
        name = askopenfilename( parent=root, initialdir='\\', initialfile='tmp', \
        filetypes=[("JPG", "*.jpg"), ("MP3", "*.mp3"), ("TXT", "*.txt")])

    Button(root , text="Try", command = tri).pack()

    root.geometry("800x800")

Comment: that is not the real program but its giving me the same error

Answer (score 1):

That is because the files should not be open using the `\`. The proper string to open files is the `\\`. That comes from the `\` is being used to escape characters, which python interpreted it like that.

```
 name = askopenfilename( parent=root, initialdir='\\', initialfile='tmp', \
 filetypes=[("JPG", "*.jpg"), ("MP3", "*.mp3"), ("TXT", "*.txt")])
```

Comment: I changed that and I still get the same error any other method to try please ? Thanks in advance

Comment: this is my error:Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
  File "try.py", line 13, in tri
  File "site-packages\tkfilebrowser\functions.py", line 142, in askopenfilename
  File "site-packages\tkfilebrowser\filebrowser.py", line 210, in __init__
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4061, in __init__
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 4006, in __init__
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:\Users\MYNAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI113162\tkfilebrowser\images\file.png": no such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

tkfilebrowser is using some images that need to be included for your software to work. here is the build command that work on my computer:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data c:\Users\eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\tkfilebrowser\images;tkfilebrowser\images mytest.py
```

Just replace c:\Users\eric\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-package with the path to your own site-package

Comment: I'm getting this Error do you know why?tkfilebrowser\image : The module 'tkfilebrowser' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module tkfilebrowser'.
At line:1 char:120
+ ... hon38\site-packages\tkifilebrowser\images\;tkfilebrowser\image try.py
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (tkfilebrowser\image:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule

Comment: @Jacob For some reason a \ was added before the ; while pasting my build command. Try and remove from yours